# Client-server app developing

Tags: client-server

As for practice project I'm making desktop(later android) pizza order app. I already made the test app with things its going to have and logic to run the processes but in order to achieve that I need client-server app. Could anyone share any general knowledge on how can It be achieved and any books/tutorials that could help me get the knowledge to get the project running.

I was making app in c#, also I stumbled upon this: http://www.networkcomms.net/

Could anyone tell me could it be achieved with this pack features?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an app is too general. but my recommendation is to built make a server first in some web technology, I work on ruby on rails you may create an api to supply the data to your client app. It does not matter if you are building your client app in javascript/html, IOS or android. your server can work across any client.

If your aim is to create an app later you could reuse the server side.

Hope it helps.

Some resources:

API book:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021575.do

Rails book:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book